# Porting comments from C# to Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I need to port lots of documentation from C# to the Java version of the project.
Once I figure out the syntax for the comments, I will need a documentation generator
for Java. Can you please recommend me some?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in the tags of your question: javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html